# IBM watson unity sdk configuration

Tags: unity-game-engine, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-discovery

I have trouble configuring IBM Watson API in unity as I cannot seem to open the `config.json.enc` file that is supposed to hold my Bluemix account credentials. Can someone please let me know how can I go about it?

According to the documentation, I should be able to open config editor but in Watson directory after copying it to the assets folder. But I see nothing like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The config.json are encrypted for internal testing purposes. After installing the SDK there should be a `Watson` menu item. Click the `Configuration Editor` on thhe top to access the Config Editor where your credentials. This will generate a Config.json in your StreamingAssets directory.

Edit:
Link to an animated gif because I can't seem to embed it. The recording software doesn't let me capture the menu bar though. The menu item says `Watson`.

http://g.recordit.co/RBogZfpwGM.gif

Edit 2:
I realize this probably would be better with a screenshot.

[image]